# memcpy - int variable to BYTE

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, memcpy

I am trying to create a data packet, using `memcpy`. I expect to see the output in `pOutBuffer`, whose first four bytes will have 999, followed by 111 followed by 12; But currently i am getting some garbage.

The problem is that instead of copying the value, it copies the address, I think. How can i copy these values in to a contiguous memory so that i can write it to disk and can retrieve the data at the receiving end with my defined format?

Thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
typedef struct
{
    int Begin;
    int End;
    int Size;
}PACKET;


void AddBuffer(PACKET* pPacket, BYTE* pOutBuffer)
{
    memcpy(pOutBuffer, &pPacket->Begin, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(pOutBuffer+sizeof(int), &pPacket->End, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(pOutBuffer+sizeof(int)+sizeof(int), &pPacket->Size, sizeof(int));
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PACKET* pPacket = new PACKET;
    pPacket->Begin = 999;
    pPacket->End   = 111;
    pPacket->Size  = 12;

    BYTE* pOutBuffer = new BYTE [pPacket->Size];
    AddBuffer(pPacket, pOutBuffer);

    //Write pOutBuffer on to the disk 
    //WriteFile(vhFileToWrite,(BYTE*)pOutBuffer,pPacket.Size,&vRetFileSize,NULL);

    //Delete pOutBuffer
    return 0;
}
```

Source sample has been updated. It now builds ok

Comment: Are you sure that this code even compiles? I'm pretty sure there are syntax errors in there.

Comment: That won't compile, you're accessing a pointer with `.`.

Comment: Does this even compile? `&pPacket.Begin` looks wrong, given ``pPacket`` is a pointer.

Comment: I wrote this simple snippet based on my large project.

Comment: @Raj: If you want us to understand your question, you need to post code that makes sense. Also, tell us what the expected and actual output are.

Comment: If you want to handle this problem cleanly I suggest you consider a serialization library like Boost.Serialization or Google Protocol Buffers. It's more complicated than it looks to do this reliably across all possible source/target machines.

Comment: @interjay, I have updated the example code, I expect to see the output in pOutBuffer, whose first four bytes will have 999, followed by 111 followed by 12; But currently i am getting some garbage.

Comment: @Steve, Mine is a windows only and for my requirement Boost seems to be over kill. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Code looks fine to me (assuming you don't transfer data between different architectures). I tested it and it worked fine. Why do you think there's a problem? What exactly do you see?

Comment: @interjay, In the step by step debug mode, After the execution of memcpy(pOutBuffer, &pPacket->Begin, sizeof(int));, You would expect to see that the value 999 being copied in to pOutBuffer; But i only see 'ç'; This is the problem

Comment: Check what you're getting again, can't see a problem at first glance... e.g. for(int i=0; i<pPacket->Size; ++i) printf("%2.2x ", pOutBuffer[i]);

Comment: @Guy, e7 03 00 00 6f 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00, is the output: it works ok. I donot know why i asked this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works correctly. On a little-endian machine with sizeof(int)==4, the number 999 will be stored as the four bytes 0xe7, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00.

You said you saw the character 'ç': That is because you are trying to view the array as a string, and ç has the character code 0xe7, which is indeed the first byte written. If you view it as an array (either using Visual Studio's memory view, or by typing `pOutBuffer,12` in the watch window), you will see the correct byte values.